# Some times In-App-Purchase delegates are not called

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am new to objective c. I have implemented in app purchase for different products in my application. It works fine, but sometimes the `SKTransactionComplete methods` which confirm the transaction are not called. I wonder if it's coding error, than why all the time it is successful but fail to response seldom?

Please give me some idea to debug the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the SKTransactionComplete methods?  SKPaymentTransactionObserver has one required method - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions.  Are you saying thats not getting called?